# Java DateTimeFormatter issue

Tags: java, date

The following code (in main)

```
LocalDate d ;
DateTimeFormatter formatter;

d = LocalDate.of(2021, 11, 14);
System.out.println(d);

formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.YYYY");
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));

formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/dd");
System.out.println(formatter.format(d)+ "\n");
            
d = LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1);
System.out.println(d);
                
formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.YYYY");
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));

formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/dd");
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

outputs in my Netbeans 12.5 with the latest or fairly recent Oracle Java 17

```
run:
2021-11-14
14.11.2021
2021/11/14

2021-01-01
01.01.2020
2020/01/01
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The formatted output for today, 14-NOV-2021, is ok, but output for 01-JAN-2021 is wrong. Formatted output prints 20**20** , one year off.

Can you repeat this? If so: Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your output. I got valid output with year as 2021. Something to do with Locale?

Comment: In my pc, it was `2021/01/01` the last output.@duaw are you  missing something? or just mistake? I think it is you env problem.

Comment: I had the same output as you. Changing the pattern to `"MM.dd.yyyy"` displayed 2021 instead of 2020

Comment: I am able to reproduce your output by changing Locale as UK. Example: DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.YYYY", Locale.UK) & DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/dd", Locale.UK)

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian Well spotted. The problem is locale dependent because different locales have different definitions of week numbers and hence of week-based-year. Which, as the answers explain, is what upper case `YYYY` gives you.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Javadoc of `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`

- **y** (lowercase) represents the *year-of-era* and
- **Y** (uppercase) represents the *week-based-year*.

The week-based date/time system is defined in ISO 8601 (see: [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)).

Answer (score 1):

You want `u`, not `Y`:

- `Y` is week-based year. If you're an accountant, this is important. If you're not, this is the devil: It seems right almost always, except in certain highly exotic dates, such as jan 1st. Weeks customarily are defined as: "Whatever year it is on the thursday of that week, that's the year that week belongs to", so if e.g. Jan 1st falls on a friday, then the week that contains Jan 1st is of the previous year (as the thursday of that week was dec 31st).
- `y` is year as you mostly know it, except it doesn't really do what you want when go to BC years. It's not likely to come up, but then neither is the week-based-year thing. Nobody likes Year-2k style bugs, right?
- `u` truly does what you imagined. It just gives you **the year**. Negative if need be.

Comment: And to make matters worse, your definition of week-based year is correct for your locale and mine, but not for all locales. *the devil* describes pretty precisely.